# How to remove a submodule from the current branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

How do you remove 'submodules' from only the current branch? I would like to keep the submodules as they are for the other branches.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody's ever taught git how to handle part-time submodules, wiping a worktree is a bit more semantically fraught than deleting a file (since worktrees tend to have lots of untracked but inconvenient-to-recreate data) so what's "the right thing to do here" is not clear at all.

You can just `git rm --cached` the entry, when you commit that git will complain, when switching to that commit from one that has the nested checkout, that it can't remove a nonempty worktree, but if you want it gone and the submodule repo's been hoisted (e.g. it's here via git submodule update, so the submodule command did the clone, or you yourself moved the repo someplace safe; either way `.git` will be a text file with `gitdir: the/repo/path`) you can just wipe it yourself.

Comment: I agree "... Nobody's ever taught git how to handle part-time submodules".

Answer (score 1):

AS @jthill answered i dont thing it something which was taken into accounts.

What you can do is to do a work around to achieve this goal.
Use git worktree

Since worktree use separate 3-states you can have branch which does not share the 3-states with the other branches and than you can remove the files from your worktree (index + workdir) and than you will not have them as part of your current branch.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot the submodule exist on the right side but is gone on the second worktree.